# What are these weird black shapes on these photos?

Tags: film-cameras, ilford, disposable-cameras

I took some photos last month with a disposable Ilford camera [like this one](https://thedarkroom.com/disposable-cameras-top-cameras-reviewed-compared/ilford-bw-hp5-single-use-disposable-camera/).

On some photos, a strange serpentine black shape can be noticed in the corner. I didn't notice anything unusual about the camera when using it.

[Here are examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKMmw.jpg).

I'm surprised, because if it was a part of the lens element coming apart, the photos wouldn't have fired or the exposure might have been wrong. Also, I can't imagine a lens element producing a shadow like this one. I'm ruling out the lab being responsible because of how it's in the corner of every photos, around the same spot.

**What are these weird dark shapes produced in this Ilford camera?**

<sup>Crops of affected area imported here for convenience</sup>

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

I looks like [swarf](https://www.google.com/search?q=swarf&tbm=isch&sxsrf=AOaemvJTG-0-MGluZaBshYVk7FjGX5xR_A%3A1633332140765&source=hp&biw=1143&bih=1329&ei=rKtaYZfaK8feapPRndgC&iflsig=ALs-wAMAAAAAYVq5vCZ-lT-ytK2IOWxFVhzGhQ6wHgnX&ved=0ahUKEwiX4LCwnLDzAhVHrxoKHZNoBysQ4dUDCAU&uact=5&oq=swarf&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6BwgjEO8DECc6CAgAELEDEIMBOggIABCABBCxA1CiCVjTEWCcGWgAcAB4AIABPogBkgKSAQE1mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWc&sclient=img) <-horribly long google images link>
Small spirals of metal or plastic that are produced when machine-cutting, lathing or drilling. Even paper will do it if caught just right.

As the piece itself is long-gone, disturbed as the camera was opened to process the film, the precise details will never be known.

As the camera was a disposable & never opened between leaving the factory & first use, then I'd say you have a claim for a refund or replacement - but you'd have to take that up with the supplier.

Comment: Hmm maybe. The triangles in the shapes are very regular though. But I should have complained, the flash didn’t work either